# How to remove the space in footer

Tags: html, css, magento

I'm quite new to HTML and CSS. And I'm doing some changes to a Magento website. Met some trouble...
Here is the website. 
[website with problem](http://chillideals.com.au/)

In footer area, there is a big white space. I totally don't know why there is a white space. I'll try my best to put all the relating code here. But basically it can be see in page source

```
<div class="footer-container<?php if($footerCssClasses) echo $footerCssClasses; ?>">
<div class="footer-container2">
  <div class="footer">


      <?php //Columns ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ?>
      <?php
      //Set minimum height of both footer columns ("footer-item")
      $linksColumnHeight = trim($themeHelper->getCfgDesign('footer/links_column_wrapper_height'));
      $colHeightStyle = ''; //CSS specifying main footer column height
      if (is_numeric($linksColumnHeight)) {
      $linksColumnHeight = (int) $linksColumnHeight;
      if ($linksColumnHeight > 0)
      //echo '<style>.footer-item { min-height:' . $linksColumnHeight . 'px; }</style>';
      $colHeightStyle = 'style="min-height:' . $linksColumnHeight . 'px;"';
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    //Get 5 static CMS blocks "i_block_footer_links_column<X>", where <X> is a number from 1 to 5
    $colCount = 0; //Number of existing column blocks
    $colHtml = array(); //Columns' content
    for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
    {
    if ($tmp_html = $this->getChildHtml('i_block_footer_links_column' . $i))
    {
    //$colHtml .= '<div class="footer-links-column-wrapper">' . $tmp_html . '</div>';
    $colHtml[] = $tmp_html;
    $colCount++;
  }
}
?>
<?php
//Check if company info block exists
$blockFooterCompanyHtml = $this->getChildHtml('i_block_footer_company');
?>
<?php //If columns or company info block exist ?>
<?php if ($colHtml || $blockFooterCompanyHtml != ''): ?>
  <div class="footer-main-bottom clearer">

    <?php //If any of the 5 blocks exist, display HTML output inside a wrapper block ?>
    <?php if ($colHtml): ?>
      <div class="footer-item wide" <?php if($colHeightStyle) echo $colHeightStyle; ?>>
        <?php
        //Set column styles, if automatic width calculation is enabled
        $colAuto = $themeHelper->getCfg('footer/links_column_auto_width');
        $colWidthStyle = ''; //CSS specifying single column width and margin
        $colWidthStyleLastCol = ''; //CSS specifying single column width and margin for the last column
        if ($colAuto && $colCount > 0)
        {
        //Calculate column and right margin width (percentage): 90% of space for column, 10% for margin
        //If there is only 1 column: width equals 100%, right margin is 0
        //IMPORTANT: Calculate margin only if there is more than 1 column (to avoid division by zero)
        if ($colCount > 1) {
        $colWidth = 90 / $colCount;
        $marginWidth = 10 / ($colCount - 1); //Subtract 1 because the last block has no right margin
      } else {
      $colWidth = 100;
      $marginWidth = 0;
    }
    $colWidthStyle = 'style="width:' .$colWidth. '%; margin-right:' .$marginWidth. '%;"';
    $colWidthStyleLastCol = 'style="width:' .$colWidth. '%; margin-right:0;"';
  }
  ?>
  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $colCount; $i++): ?>
    <?php //If the last column: replace the width style with the width style for the last column
    if ($i+1 == $colCount)
    $colWidthStyle = $colWidthStyleLastCol;
    ?>
    <div class="footer-links-column-wrapper" <?php if($colWidthStyle) echo $colWidthStyle; ?>>
      <?php echo $colHtml[$i]; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endfor; ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('.footer-links-column-wrapper'), ['last'])</script>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is part of footer's code.
The whole part of code is very very long...

CSS for this part:

```
.footer-container { 
  background:url(../images/img/footer-gray.png) center 0 repeat;
}

.footer-container2 {
  background:url(../images/img/footer-bg-top-line.png) center 0 repeat-x;
 }

.footer {
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  text-align:left;
  background:url(../images/img/footer-bg-plus.png) center 50px no-repeat;
  color:#555; /* DESIGN: footer text color */
}

.footer a { 
  color:#555; /* DESIGN: footer link color */ 
}
.footer a:hover {
  color:#a60404; /* DESIGN: footer link color hover */ 
}
.footer .heading { 
  color:#333; 
 } /* DESIGN: footer heading color */

.mclear { clear:both; } /* my: additional simple clearing */
```

So.. Any suggestions?
I was thinking is it because the background image is too small? but actually is repeating. so this guess is wrong.

Comment: remove background from `.footer-container2` and `.footer` classes

Comment: It is because of min-height property, set to your footer-item wide class. You can remove it to get desired output

Comment: Hi thanks guys for fast replying. Already fixed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

white space coming from background image in `.footer-container2` class. Just remove it.

```
.footer-container2 {
  background:url(../images/img/footer-bg-top-line.png) center 0 repeat-x;
}
```

And Also shadow image coming from your `.footer` class. also remove this.

```
.footer {
    background: url("../images/img/footer-bg-plus.png") no-repeat  center 50px;
}
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your footer has a background set:

```
.footer {
    background:url(../images/img/footer-bg-plus.png) center 50px no-repeat;
}
```

Remove that and you should be fine.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'd appreciate if you select this as accepted answer then, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the screenshot below you have mentioned 140px as min-width, remove that.

https://snag.gy/8YrXCJ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If this is how you wanted [image]

Please add below styles to .footer-item.wide

```
.footer-item.wide {
width: 100%;
min-height: auto !important;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. But this is not what I want. I already fixed it thanks to Mukesh. But thanks anyway. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**The first.** I the `.foooter-bottom`'s `padding` is `20px`. Change it to `0` from top eg. `padding: 0 0 20px 20px;` if you want 20px to the bottom and left.

**The second.** In the `.footer-item` `padding` change padding eg. to `50px 0 0 20px;`.

**And the last.** Look at your code here:

```
<div class="footer-main-bottom clearer">
  <div class="footer-item wide" style="min-height: 140px;">...
```

You don't need the `min-height` property if you want reduce the white-space. Set it e.g. to `90px`. You can also delete unnessesary `padding` and `margin` properties in other `div` - just use any code inspector in your browser (e.g. Mozilla Firefox).

**This is the effect of my tips above.**
[image]